# setting size with css

Tags: jquery, css

i have a problem..my tabs name show too big i want it shows as a default...
i put this script at `<head>`..

```
<style type="text/css">
                { font-family: Verdana; font-size:40%; }
                label { width: 15em; float: left; }
                label.error {display: none; float: none; color: red; padding-left: .5em; vertical-align: top; }
                p { clear: both; }
                .submit { margin-left: 12em; }
                 em { font-weight: bold; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align: top; }

        </style>



        <style type="text/css">
                body 
                {
                        font-family:Times new roman, verdana;
                        font-size:22px;
                        width: 850px;
                        margin-left: auto;
                        margin-right: auto;
                        margin-top: 6px;
                        background-image:url("wood_texture2.jpg");
                }
        </style>
```

it makes all setting inside `<body>` in same size..where is my fault?how to make separate size for each item inside body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a syntax error on the first line of your css

```
{ font-family: Verdana; font-size:40%; }
```

Maybe it should be

```
body { font-family: Verdana; font-size:40%; }
```

Comment: it for setting label error...for body is below that code which use "Times Newroman"

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `width`-attribute within the body-style-declaration. It doesn't make any sense. Instead set the width/height for each element you want to give a special size:

```
div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #F00;
}
```

As you already did with `.sumbit` in your code use classes for the same html-elements which should have different styles.

Comment: in my case..if i'm not use width n height my form wil show full screen at monitor...

Comment: than apply the width and height attributes to your form-tag. `form {width: 500px;}`